# How should I set a static final variable based on user input?

Tags: java, static, initialization, final

I am trying to model the classic water jug problem in AI. I have made a class "JugsState" that stores the current state of two jugs, i.e. how many liter of water is in jug1 and how many liter of water in jug2. In addition, I want to store the maximum amount of water each jug can hold, which I will take from the user as input. Since this(capacity of the two jugs) will be constant throughout , I am declaring them as static final variables. But I am unable to initialize them inside the constructor. Is there any other alternative to this, which maintains the encapsulation of max_jug variables inside the class JugsState?

```
class JugsState
{
    private static final int max_jug1,max_jug2;
    private int jug1,jug2; //stores the current amount of water in the jugs.

    JugsState(int a1,int a2)
    {
        max_jug1 = a1;
        max_jug2 = a2;
    }
}
```

error: "cannot assign a value to final variable max_jug1"
error: "cannot assign a value to final variable max_jug2"

Comment: If the user can set it, it's not a constant.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I want the user to set it only once.

Comment: Then remove the `static` key word and keep the `final` keyword.

Comment: Then only allow input once.

Comment: @Tom But won't that make max_jug1's and max_jug2's copy for each instance of the class? The class represents the current state of the jugs.

Comment: Correct. Re-think your current code: what will happen if you create another instance of `jug`? You would initialize `max_jug1` and `max_jug2` a second time, but you're trying to avoid that. You can't use static variables here, because both jugs can hold different amounts of liquid. So refactor your code so one `jug` instance describes only one jug (as Dimas answer suggests).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change a `final` variable because it is `final`. However, you *can* set it to anything you want when it is declared. You can create a static function that gets the maximum for a jar. It could be something like this, if you want to get it from System.in:

```
private static int getMax(){
    System.out.println("Enter the maximum for a jar:");
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    return in.nextInt();
}
```

Then use

```
private static final int max_jug1=getMax();
private static final int max_jug2=getMax();
```

in place of

```
private static final int max_jug1, max_jug2;
```

That will set those variables for the rest of the time that the program runs.

Comment: how should I declare getMax()?

Comment: @user3526682 It should be a static function that returns the user's choice for the maximum.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit with an example? that would be very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your class represents a jug, it should not hold information about **two** jugs. 
`maxAmount` or `volume` should be a non-static member of the class:

```
public class Jug {
    public final double volume;
    private double currentAmount = 0;
    public Jug(double vol) { volume = vol; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Quite right. But, suppose there are two jugs: A(max 6) and B(max 4). In one state they have (1,2) volumes then in another state they have (2,3) volumes. How should I store the information contained in the states?

Comment: notice the `currentAmount` variable? That's the one to hold the current state.

Comment: suppose there are n states of a single jug, then the information about max volume is repeated n times. I want it to be stored only once(to prevent discrepancy and to remove redundancy).

Comment: You don't need to keep all states around. Just the current state is enough. If you did want to preserve the history of a given jug's states, make it an array inside the `Jug`. The important thing here is to not confuse an a object with its state, and its properties, they are three different things.

Comment: My program deals with only a fixed number of jugs. That's why state as a class variable is more important to me.(I am making state transition Graph). So I think I have given a wrong name to the class, instead I should have named it "JugsState".What do you think?

Comment: No, I think, the name is fine. You gave it the wrong members :) I mean, sure, you can get rid of `class Jug`, and just have `maxVolume1, state1[], maxVolume2, state2[]` instead. It would work. Just wold not be an object-oriented design. If you make everything static (and also public), you can, pretty much, write "C" code in java syntax. It is possible to do, and it will work, but ... what's the point?

Comment: There is some constraint(max_volumes) on the possible states, and that should be stored as an information in the class state itself. And since that information is applicable to all states, it should be stored as a class variable(static). Suppose max_vols be (6,8), current state be (4,6) and we define a transition by transferring as much water as possible from jug1 to jug2. Then the information of max volumes will be useful to carry out that transition.

Comment: No, the logic that transfers water between jugs does not belong to the `Jug`. It should be in the outside method (like `main` or wherever): `jug2.add(jug1.remove(Math.min(jug1.curAmount, jug2.max - jug2.curAmount))));` Or, maybe, just `jug2.addAllFrom(jug1);` if it is used often enough to be of a utility.

Answer (score -1):

If a variable is `static`, then it would be re-initialized every time the constructor is called. If it is `final` it can be set only once. 
Something close to what you described could be the following (notice the static method `setMaxJug1` )

```
   class jug
    {
        private static int max_jug1,max_jug2;
        private int jug1,jug2; //stores the current amount of water in the jugs.
        jug(){
          // Your constructor stuff
        }
        public static void setMaxJug1(int m){
           max_jug1 = m;
        }
    }
```

Then in the main you can call

```
 jug.setMaxJug1(m);
```

Probably there are other ways of doing what you ask, but I tried not to change too much of your code.

Just to mention, one alternative is to have those variables not static, as in:

```
class jug
        {
            private final int max_jug1,max_jug2;
            private int jug1,jug2; //stores the current amount of water in the jugs.
            jug(int a1,int a2)
             {
               max_jug1 = a1;
               max_jug2 = a2;
             }   
        }
```

Then you could use your original constructor. However, every `jug` Object will have (in general) a different value for `max_jug1` and `max_jug2`, depending on the values (`a1,a2`) you pass in the constructor.

The right choice depends on how you want to use jug objects.

Comment: "*If a variable is static, then it cannot be set in the constructor as it does not belong only to the Object being constructed.*" This is certainly not true.

Comment: Where should I declare setMaxJug1()? I am not so much experienced in java and when should I call it?

Comment: The static method can be set anywhere in the class jug, clearly outside any other method, and outside the constructor. I edited the code to show an example.

Comment: How should I pass a value to setMaxJug1 based on user input? In the main function?

Comment: @Dima I expressed myself better editing the post, with a less categorical statement.

Comment: @GioPan, it may be less categorical, but is still wrong. There is nothing wrong with setting static variables in a constructor, and there are many examples of use cases when it might be useful. This is just not one of them, but not because you should not be setting static variables in constructors, but because these particular variables simply should not be static.

Comment: @user3526682 As an example, in the main, you can call ´jug.setMaxJug2(m);´ where ´m´ is the int you get from the user (or wherever else)

Comment: @user3526682 You should note that these variables are not `final` anymore. That means you can call `#setMaxJug1` as often as you want.

Comment: @Dima it seems we are saying the same thing: this is not a case where to set static variables in the constructor. I also would not model those variables as static, but I want to believe the user has some reasons for doing that.

Comment: @GioPan, no, we are not saying the same thing. I am saying they should not be static, and you are saying they should not be set in the constructor. These are very different things.

Comment: @GioPan: Thanks buddy, but I think Tom's answer was more exact. but thanks again! Your answer was helpful too. You made me understand the concept of static methods.